# Salvando caminho de arquivo no MySQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Estou tendo dificuldade ao salvar endereço de arquivo no banco de dados. Ao salvar o endereço no banco ele esta adicionando a quantidade de vezes que utilizei o `OpenFileDialog` para salvar um arquivo.

Salva o endereço sempre assim  `C:\Users\phili\Desktop\PDF_SGIM_QUALIDADE_CNH\certificadocalibracao.pdf12`

Sempre coloca um numeral depois da extensão.

Porque está acontecendo isso?

```
private void tsbtnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (identificacaoTextBox.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Informe a Identificação do Instrumento.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    identificacaoTextBox.Focus();
                }

                else if (descricaoTextBox.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Informe s Descrição do Instrumento.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    descricaoTextBox.Focus();
                }

                else
                {
                    if (status == "novo")
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tb_Intrumento (identificacao,Descricao,Marca, Modelo,Serial,Capacidade,Frequencia,Data_Calibracao,Vencimento_Calibrecao,Certificado) VALUES('" + identificacaoTextBox.Text + "','" + descricaoTextBox.Text + "','" + marcaTextBox.Text + "','" + modeloTextBox.Text + "','" + txb_Numero_Serie.Text + "','" + capacidadeTextBox.Text + "','" + tcb_Frequencia_Calibracao.Text + "','" + txb_Data_Calibracao.Text + "','" + txb_Vencimento_Calibracao.Text + "','" + txb_caminho.Text + "','" +
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        MessageBox.Show("Registro salvo com sucesso.", "Salvar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }

                    else if (status == "editar")
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tb_Instrumento SET Identificacao='" + identificacaoTextBox.Text + "',  Descricao='" + descricaoTextBox.Text + "',Marca='" + marcaTextBox.Text + "', Modelo='" + modeloTextBox.Text + "', Serie='" + txb_Numero_Serie.Text + "', Capacidade='" + capacidadeTextBox.Text + "', Frequencia='" + tcb_Frequencia_Calibracao.Text + "', Data_Calibracao='" + txb_Data_Calibracao.Text + "', Vencimento_Calibracao='" + txb_Vencimento_Calibracao.Text + "', Certificado='"  + txb_caminho.Text +
                             lstvInstrumentos.Items[lstvInstrumentos.FocusedItem.Index].Text + "'";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Registro atualizado com sucesso.", "Atualizar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    carregaVariaveis();
                    btn_Limpar_Dados.PerformClick();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Abaixo segue código que insere o caminho no `textbox`:

```
private void btn_Carregar_Certificado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog abrir = new OpenFileDialog();
            abrir.ShowDialog();

           // openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            txb_caminho.Text = abrir.FileName.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
        }
```

Comment: Fora o enorme problema de segurança, os nomes de variáveis que não seguem o padrão de nomenclatura do C# e eu não entender porque do `Replace`, não vi porque isto está ocorrendo. Até onde eu sei a propriedade `FileName` não gera isto por conta própria. Tente isolar o problema.

Comment: Retirei o replace, mas mesmo assim o erro continua. Ao salvar o caminho no banco de dados ele adiciona o numeral após o final do caminho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `cmd.CommandText` do `if (status == "novo")` está concatenando a próxima linha junto com a query.
Sendo que a próxima linha é o `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`, que retorna o `Id` do insert que ela acabou de realizar.

Portanto basta colocar um `;` depois da do `txb_caminho.Text` ao invés de como está agora:  `_Calibracao.Text + "','" + txb_caminho.Text + "','" +`.

Comment: Vou corrigir esse ponto e executar a aplicação, assim que tiver o resultado volto a te falar. Obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Faça a *query* de forma segura e o problema vai se resolver:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tb_Instrumento SET Identificacao = @Identificao, Descricao = @Descricao, ... aqui vai colocar todos os campos ..., Certificado = @Certificado, ... pode ter outros aqui", connection);

cmd.Parameters["@Identificacao"].Value = identificacaoTextBox.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@Descricao"].Value = descricaoTextBox.Text;
... todos os parâmetros aqui
cmd.Parameters["@Certificado"].Value = txb_caminho.Text;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/SafeInsert2.cs).

O código do jeito que está não está só errado, tem sérios problemas de segurança.

Comment: Fui corrigido por isso, por não utilizar Parameters. Estou tentando aprofundar meu conhecimento, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Mesmo que o problema esteja corrigido, vale a pena alterar o seu código para seguir este padrão. Usando essa alternativa pode parecer mais complicado inicialmente, mas facilita muito a manutenção, para que no futuro seja mais fácil identificar outros erros...

Comment: Vou alterar todo o código do sistema, seguir o conselho que foi dado por vocês. Foi falta de experiência mesmo. Irei tentar criar classes para gerenciar esses dados. Vou pesquisar mais sobre o assunto e tentar aplicar, não tenho muito conhecimento sobre gerenciamento do projeto, apesar de ser formado na área. Obrigado pelas dicas, serão de grande valia...

Comment: @PhilipeSaid você está tendo algum problema para usar o site? Eu vi que você trocou a aceitação da resposta algumas vezes? A que está aceita agora é a que você deseja aceitar mesmo? Você pode escolher qualquer uma delas, mas apenas uma. E pode votar em todas. O seu comentário diz que vai adotar o que eu respondi, mas aceita a outra, fica estranho.

Comment: Estou com dificuldades sim, primeira vez que utilizo o site. Tentei votar nas duas, por isso essa confusão.

Comment: @PhilipeSaid dá uma lida no [tour], a aceitação só pode uma (é como o *radio button*), o voto pode em tudo no site todo, não só nas suas coisas. Aí a decisão é sua de qual você considera melhor para sua pergunta. Não tem problema se escolher a outra, só quero que faça isto de forma consciente, não porque não entendeu o mecanismo e a aceita foi por sorte.