# Como criar a linha de comando de atualizar campos a partir da placa

Tags: c#

Estou com um trabalho para inserir, atualizar e deletar. O inserir e deletar estão funcionando corretamente. Logo, tenho um problema no código de *update* que seria isso:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Update carros set placa='" + campoplaca.Text + "', marca='" + campomarca.Text + "' where placa='" + campoplaca.Text + "' and marca= '" + campomarca.Text + "'";
```

Em meu projeto tenho como valores :

```
id=int pk
placa=nvarchar
marca=nvarchar
modelo=nvarchar
combustivel=nvarchar
potencia=int
ano=int
preco=int
```

Logo minha dúvida é de como prosseguir com essa linha de comando. Onde já existe placa e marca, o meu desejo do *where* é que se altere pela placa e depois os demais campos. Mais sera preciso o *and* em todos?

```
private void btAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCeConnection(" Data Source = C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\WindowsFormsArrayEx03\\BD_Teste.sdf; Password ='' ");
                conn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("ATUALIZADO!!!");

            SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "Update carros set placa='" + campoplaca.Text + "', marca='" + campomarca.Text + "' where placa='" + campoplaca.Text + "' and marca= '" + campomarca.Text + "'";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Na verdade nem se coloca and para update. A placa é sua chave primária?

Comment: Essa forma de fazer tem um erro fundamental. Há uma enorme falha de segurança. Se começar resolver isso, já é um bom caminho para consertar o resto. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104614/101. OU http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136287/101 (olha a mais votada, a ceita insiste no erro).

Comment: @GabrielFalieri se coloca "and" ou "or" sim para update se precisar. Não há restrições. Cuidado com afirmações generalizadas.

Comment: a minha chave primaria é id, mas logo não usarei ele para atualizar e sim a placa

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, não é aconselhável concatenar instruções sql como você fez.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update carros set placa='" + campoplaca.Text + "', marca='" + campomarca.Text + "' where placa='" + campoplaca.Text + "' and marca= '" + campomarca.Text + "'";
```

Veja uma possibilidade para seu exemplo, faça seu `where` usando a chave primária da tabela. Assim dessa forma você consegue alterar tanto a `placa` como a `marca` em uma mesma instrução `update`.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update carros set placa=@placa, marca=@marca where id=@id";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@placa", Value = placa });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@marca", Value = marca });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@id", Value = id});
```

Comment: Obrigado irei testar

Comment: eu acabei utilizando o código assim , mas creio que o problema pode ser na hora de atualizar os parametros em int como potencia,ano e preco

Comment: Boa, aqui os motivos para usar dessa forma. http://www.cdvagabundo.com.br/imagens/sql-injection-urbano .... e  https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL